# Duplicated strings about provider error in SO localization engine

Tags: support, localization

I found the [almost duplicated strings](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=There%20was%20an%20error%20fetching%20your%20account%20from) in SO localization engine:

> [image: error fetching all of these]

Is there a real reason to not to use the following single form?

> There was an error fetching your account from $provider$.  Please try logging in again.

Using the single universal form is easy to translate.

Comment: But at least one advantage of using multiple strings is that provider name can also be translated.